# React Native - Invalid hook call. hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: react-native, mobile

This is the code implementation in screenshot. I just created a simple application that contains one button and one input field where I'm saving the input text and printing in the log on console after button press but it shows in error with `**const [enterGoal, setGoalState] = useState('')**`. Can someone have a look on it?

[image: code implementation screenshot]
[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using a class component and hooks are meant to be used in functional components. So thats the error. If you are using class try using `setState` method to update state and also define states in constructor. like

```
constructor(props){
this.state={
nameOfPerson:'robert'
}
}
```

and inside any function do `this.setState({nameOfPerson:'wowo'})` to change it,,

Comment: Do Mark as accepted and upvote if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are using hooks in class components .hooks are working in functional componets

for example

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

for more check [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)